# Is the phrase "that guy so inch" related to Putonghua?

Tags: slang

I came across the phrase "that guy so inch" in [this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/jeannette_ng/status/1002890390977073152), which starts with:

> ... slang based on literal translations of words ("that guy so inch") or phrases

I don't get how "that guy so inch" could be related to Putonghua. Is it something to do with 村/英村?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Cantonese

> [串](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1310/) /cyun3 /
>
> *[7] [粵] [adj] arrogant; cocky | [Var] 寸*

"that guy so inch" is literal translations of "嗰條友咁寸(串)" in Cantonese.

The 'arrogant; cocky' definition of 串 is not used in Mandarin.

"嗰條友咁串" in Mandarin would be "那傢伙太囂張了" meaning "that guy is so arrogant"

> [咁串](http://www.yueyv.cn/dacidian/view/index131003.html)
>
> *太嚣张了。*